# Display nested objects from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an api that returns an array of objects. within those objects there are nested objects and within those  nested objects there are more nested objects. The data looks like this:

```
data = [{
   incident: '1',
   incidentdt: '1/1/2010',
    CriticalInc: [{
        IncidentType: '1',
        CIDT: '1/2/2010',{

   incident: '2',
   incidentdt: '1/1/2010',
    AssoINC: [{
        ASIID: '1',
        Ofc: [{
            OFC_ID: '111'}, {
            name: 'DAVE'}]},
        Ofc: [{
            OFC_ID: '121'}, {
            name: 'John'}]},  
}]
```

Console.log(data) will return an array of objects with nested objects. If I type in console.log(angular.toJson(data)) will return the data in JSON format.

My angular code is

```
<td>{{a.incident}}</td>
<td>{{a.incidentdt}}</td>
<td>{{a.IncidentType}}</td>
<td>{{a.name }}</td>
```

The only thing that displays is:

```
<td>{{a.incident}}</td>
<td>{{a.incidentdt}}</td>
```

The nested objects below that will not display. Please help as I do not understand how to display the nested objects.

Comment: You have an array of objects nested in that json, like you said, so you can't use a.IncidentType, you can loop on it for example, `<div ng-repeat="c in a.CriticalInc">{{c.IncidentType}}</div>`

Comment: This is perfect. Would this work the same way as <div ng-repeat="c in a.AssocINC.Ofc">{{c.name}}</div>?  because it's not displaying anything or do I have to ng-repeat down further? @LukeHutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation to display your data. I.e.

```
<td>{{a.CriticalInc[0].IncidentType}}</td>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `{{a.CriticalInc[0].IncidentType}}`?

Comment: Yes, or loop on it: `<div ng-repeat="c in a.CriticalInc">{{c.IncidentType}}</div>`

Comment: @BlakeMumford, this works as well as the loop. Great, I tried to dot down further for the other object like this: <td>{{a.AssocINC[0].Ofc[0].name}}</td> and it appears to not work. Is there a different method for that?